# Keeping duplicates and deleting rest from pandas dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have 3 different pandas dataframe, which I have concatenated. Now I would like to keep only those rows which appear in three columns and delete the rest. For instance

```
  Column1  Column2 Column3 

0 John       a      Sam
1 Sam        b      Rob
2 Daniel     c      John
3 Varys      d      Ella
```

I want to keep only those rows in  `Column1`, which appear in both `Column1` and `Column2`. In the above example its ROW -- 0 & 1.

Desired output

```
  Column1  Column2 

0 John       a    
1 Sam        b
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter the df by pass the series `'Column3'` as an arg to [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) to test for membership:

```
In [42]:
df[df['Column1'].isin(df['Column3'])]

Out[42]:
  Column1 Column2 Column3
0    John       a     Sam
1     Sam       b     Rob
```